# Recognizing involution functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$f(x) = \frac {3x+11}{x-3} , x\ne 3$$
I tried making $x$ the subject in the equation but that didnt work.
the question says to find $f^{-1}$ in terms of $x$ and explain what the inverse implies about the symmetry of the graph of $y=f(x)$

Comment: Alt. hint: $\;y = \frac {3x\color{red}{-9+9}+11}{x-3}=3 +\frac{20}{x-3} \iff (x-3)(y-3)=20\,$. The LHS of the latter is symmetric in $x,y$, which means that if $(x,y)$ satisfies the equation then so does $(y,x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order to find $f^{-1}$ we need to find the function $g$ such that $$(f\circ g )(x) = x$$ and $$(g\circ f)(x)=x$$ taking the first equation we have that $$f(g(x))=x \hspace{2mm} \Rightarrow \hspace{2mm} \frac{3g(x)+11}{g(x)-3}=x.$$ Can you unravel this equation for $g(x)$? $$$$ Hopefully, you notice that $g=f^{-1}=f$ making $f$ involutory. This means that $f$ is symmetric over the line $y=x.$